# How to make a border left with custom bullet for my list, in a gradient style?

Tags: html, css

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Items with white background are my list items. On the left side I want to have a border, with custom bullets (custom, since we cannot change the default list bullet color -black- AFAIK). The upper part of the border should have a gradient color, from transparent to grey color for instance. As you also see in the pic, the length of the border should be longer than the actual list height (until the plus button, not till the last item ends.)

I have actually achieved some parts but i would like to know a better, cleaner way of doing it.

This is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/6esLm8q1/

```css
.list {
  list-style: none;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(179,179,179)) 0 0 0 1;
}

.item {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: -1.7em;
}

.item::before {
  content: "\2022";
  color: grey;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 1em;
  margin-left: -1em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
<li class="item">
Test1
</li>
<li class="item">
Test2</li>
</ul>

<button>Plus
</button>
```

Problems are still: Aligning of bullets to item text, even if I align the bullets on the border, when I resize the window, the bullets slides to left or right slightly.

The gradient line is far more transparent at the beginning, not actually like in the "Target" pic. And the border ends where the list items end, so it does not reach until the button.

I appreciate any help till I get something close to my target pic!

Answer (score 1):

You got yourself 99% there. For the `linear-gradient`, if you define the end-point to be lower than `100%`, then you get it to fade earlier. Otherwise, it calculates the end point to be `100%` and thus half of your border looks faded.

For the `before` psuedo-element, since in your markup you put a `p` tag within each `li`, you should put the pseudo-element on the `p` tag itself.

See the snippet below.

```css
.list {
  list-style: none;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,  rgba(179,179,179) 40%) 0 0 0 1; /* add % to have gradient end earlier than end */
}

/* add before pseudo-element on p tag (since you include it in your markup */
.item>p:before {
  content: "\2022";
  color: grey;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: -2.7em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item">
        <p>
            Test1
        </p>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <p>
            Test2
        </p>
    </li>
</ul>

<button>Plus</button>
```

Comment: Of course, if you have more items within each `li`, you should put the pseudo-element back on the `li` tag and add position it absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is already pretty good. I would create the circles with `border-radius`, as you have more control over the sizing and position.

Here is an example:

```css
.list {
  list-style: none;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(179, 179, 179)) 0 0 0 1;
  margin: 0 0 0 1em;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
}

.item:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: grey;
  left: -2.75em;
  top: .4em;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  margin: -.2em 0 0 .25em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #c00;
  color: white;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">
    <p>Test1<br>test with line break</p>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <p>Test2<br>test with<br>two line breaks</p>
  </li>
</ul>
<button>+</button>


<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">
    <p>Test1</p>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <p>Test2</p>
  </li>
</ul>
<button>+</button>
```

Comment: border-radius is also a great tipp thanks! do you have any idea how i can center-align the bullet points to my list-items? I can of course give some "top: .1em" to the bullets, but they have different heights in my case (they are not simple texts, but some divs in real app)

Comment: ok i have achieved that with "display: flex" and "align-items: center" on the list items.. thanks!

Comment: sry, I was afk O:) Yes, flex would be a suitable approach here, I think!

Answer (score 0):

Is it critical to be plain css? From my point of view you're trying to solve the issue with the wrong instruments.

What if you split the element, making the line on the left and the bullet with separate elements, positioned absolutely in the padding region of the container, and the content in subcontinent?

Something like this:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ededed;
}

.tail {
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 2px;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(179,179,179)) 0 0 0 1;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.list {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgba(179,179,179);
  list-style: disc;
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(179,179,179);
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.item {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.item > div {
  color: #555;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: sans;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

button {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #b30920;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 33px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tail"></div>
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item"><div>Test1</div></li>
  <li class="item"><div>Test2<br>test</div></li>
</ul>

<button>+</button>
```

Comment: Edited the answer, may be this way it serves better